# adding horizental lines

Tags: line

how can I add a horizental line above my page and write above it. like that
[image]

Comment: You are looking for a feature called "headers".  You can search this site.  See also the `fancyhdr` package.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: See here for example: https://overleaf.com/learn/latex/Headers_and_footers

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that is based on [here](https://overleaf.com/learn/latex/Headers_and_footers). The manual for the package `fancyhdr` can be found [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr).

```
% Based on https://overleaf.com/learn/latex/Headers_and_footers

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % <-- Important package!

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % Clear all header and footer fields and then re-define the field, see below.
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Overleaf}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{Guides and tutorials}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

% E for even page
% O for odd page
% L for left side
% C for centered
% R for right side

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{10pt} % <-- Width of head line
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt} % <-- Width of foot line

\begin{document}

\blinddocument[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer but I'm using lyx ,so I can't write all this ,I can only insert code tex .

Comment: I do not understand your comment, sorry. Most likely because I have never used LyX.