# How can I write above the horizontal line on LyX?

Tags: lyx

I want to write the name of my chapter above this horizontal line, I'm using LyX.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. How did you add that line in the first place? If it's made by Insert -> Formatting -> Horizontal line for example, just delete it, and insert a new line where you want it to be.

Comment: Do you mean writing the chapter title in the header, per chance?

Comment: yes I mean  the chapter title in the header  @Bernard

Comment: I don't use Lyx, but there's latex code behing. Usually this is done with the `fancyhdr` package, with (a bit easier) the `titleps`, a companion package of  `titlesec`.

Comment: Similar to your last question [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/601023/adding-horizental-lines], you can have a look at the fancyhdr package. The code in the provided answer shows \leftmark and \rightmark which is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: thnk you for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Document</kbd> → <kbd>Settings</kbd>:

1. `Document Class` → Select  <kbd>Book (Standard Class)</kbd>
2. → `Page Layout` → `Page style` → Select <kbd>fancy</kbd>

Note that this will make a header (with the rule, that should not be in them main screen) in the second and following pages, but not in the chapter page, because a header just above of a huge title is really useless, but if you have some problem with this, you can go under the chapeter title and type  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and `\thispagestyle{fancy}` in the evil red box.

If you wnat something more complex with header, go to <kbd>Document</kbd> → <kbd>Settings</kbd> → `LaTeX preamble` to set `fancyhdr` headers manually.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer @Fran  the first method worked and I got the hearders ,but I dont know how to write above it

Comment: @ImeneYd In `View` → `Code Preview Pane`  → `Complete Source` you can see that the above just insert `\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancy}` in the LaTeX preamble,, but as said above, you can edit directly the preamble to add manually  `\usepackage{fancyhdr}  ...`,  where `...` is the commands of the package that you want. See the `fancyhdr` manual or the examples of the [questions about fancyhdr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fancyhdr?tab=Votes) in this site.

Comment: +1: I did not know about the `<kbd>Document</kbd>` syntax, cool!

Comment: Thank you so much